# React: Fastest way to reach document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please, tell me, if there are any methods to access the document immediately after its initialization?

I have the following situation, I want to reload the page **immediately**, if there is a specific query in the URL.

Ideally, I would like to do this inside `ComponentWillMount()`, before react starts to render the page. But, unfortunately, I do not understand how best to do it. Now I can interact with the `document` only inside `ComponentDidMount()`

Perhaps, and most likely, I am doing something wrong. I would be grateful for any of your advice.

Comment: Can you add little bit more info about the url/query and why you need to reload? Will a route change work?

Comment: please read my comment on the Sora Shiro answer, there I described my situation in detail

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code to explain more clearly to your question? I think you may solve it by:

1. Place a empty div (z-index: 999), then check if there is a specific query in the URL. If there is, then redirect. This can use in `ComponentDidMount()` or `useEffect()`
2. But I don't understand why you must do this. It makes sense that you can redirect whenever, which means that showing a temp page is not bad

Comment: I have the following situation. We want create a separate link to our posts for users of one of our social networks, which will generate a html page, independent of the React, with content from our backend.

I wrote all the necessary code, and at the moment I want to get a result in which the user, when following the link, does not see the load of the React. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya You can do this by Next.js, which is good at server rendering.It can redirect by using router, so when you query `http://xxx/profile?userId=1` , it can detect params and generate html to client. But that's not the only way to do. I think you can make a rule that when url is like `http://xxx/profile?userId=1`, then server can make a branch logic to generate page. This can do by any language framework or even Nginx